# socket.io .emit() from client not work ( on webpack server/client configs )

Tags: webpack, socket.io, client, emit

Using SOCKET.IO the .emit() from client side doesn't work.
I'm working in localhost with two different client and server webpack configs.
I'm trying to emit a message from client with the server in listening and after print that message on client.
Here the code:

**server.js**

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With']
  }
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connect', onConnect);
server.listen(port, () => console.log('server listening on port ' + port));

function onConnect(socket){
    socket.emit('chat', 'Hello from Server');
    socket.on('chat', function(msg) {
        socket.emit(msg)
    });
}
```

**client.js** (imported in index.js)

```
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('init');
    socket.on('connect', onConnect);

    function onConnect() {
        console.log('connect ' + socket.id);
        socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnect ' + socket.id));

        socket.emit('chat', 'Hi from Client');
        socket.on('chat', function(msg) {
            console.log(msg)
        });
    }
```

**RESULT:**

```
init
connect 5ePdFlYijgD6n9AoAAAH
Hello from Server
```

---

I share my webpack's configs too, maybe they are usefull...
They are 2 different config's files. The client is run with target:web, else the server is run with target:node.

webpack.server.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: './src/server.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'server.js'
    }
  };
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: './src/index.js',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',   // for development build only
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',                        // for development build only
        // filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',     // for production build only
    },
    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: "[path].gz[query]",
            algorithm: "gzip",
            test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                  'style-loader',   // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                  'css-loader',     // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                  'sass-loader',    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the problem is in client.js, you are creating socket event inside the onConnect Event, you need to crease separate listeners for each event such as socket.on('connect', onConnect);socket.on('chat',onChat); socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnect);

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on server connection. Should use io.sockets.on() instead io.on().
I share my correct server.js code that works perfectly.

**server.js**

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With']
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
io.sockets.on('connect', onConnect);

let msgs = []

function onConnect(socket){

    socket.emit('load',msgs)
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
      socket.emit('messages',msg)
      socket.broadcast.emit('messages',msg)
      msgs.push(msg)
    });

}
```